# linking assembly object file with C object file on OS X and can't find symbol

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

I have a library defined in `libadd.asm`, it exposes one "function" `_add`. I have a `.c` source file that refers to `add` and I'm trying to get the two object files to link, but am encountering this error regardless of the order in which I link the object files:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_add", referenced from:
      _main in prog.o
```

Here's the code:

```
// prog.c
#include <stdio.h>

int add();

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", add(4, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the assembly file. It almost certainly doesn't respect the appropriate calling convention. I don't really understand what I should be doing to shuffle the values between registers. (That's what I was trying to figure out originally.)

```
; libadd.asm
_add:
add eax, edx
ret
```

Here's what I'm using to the tiny project. I'm intentionally shadowing the implicit `.c.o` rule with one that does as little as possible and ignores `*FLAGS`. I'm using `cc` to drive the linker because that's the simplest way I know to link in the c runtime/standard library/whatever it's called. I've always tried linking with `prog.o` and `libadd.o` in the other order.

```
all: prog

prog: prog.o libadd.o
    $(CC) -o prog $^

%.o: %.asm
    nasm -f macho64 -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(wildcard *.o)
```

running make produces the following output

```
cc -c -o prog.o prog.c
nasm -f macho64 -o libadd.o libadd.asm
cc -o prog prog.o libadd.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_add", referenced from:
      _main in prog.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [prog] Error 1
Exit 2
```

`libadd.o` gets assembled successfully and appears to have the right symbol in it.

```
% nm libadd.o
0000000000000000 t _add
```

Why is `ld` complaining that it can't find the symbol?

Comment: You need to export the symbol, e.g. using `global _add`

Comment: Thanks. How did `nm` find the symbol when I left that off? Alternatively, why was it in the object file in the first place?

Comment: `man nm` says: _"If lowercase, the symbol is usually local; if uppercase, the symbol is global (external)"_.  Apparently `nasm` puts the locals into the symbol table too, could be helpful for debugging or something.

Comment: @Jester `gas` does the same thing and that's actually the expected behaviour.